# Retraction and deformation retraction

Tags: general-topology

Does either or both a retraction or a deformation retraction between to topological spaces induce a homeomorphism between their fundamental groups?

Comment: Do you mean a **homomorphism** between their fundamental groups? Any continuous map induces one of those?

Comment: I apologise, I posed in haste due to an impending exam. Ignore me and forgive my stupidity ;)

Comment: Maybe you mean an *isomorphism* (algebraic analogue of homeomorphism)?

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous map $f: X \to Y$ will induce a homomorphism $f_\sharp: \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$, which sends a loop $l: S^1 \to X$ in $X$ to the loop $f \circ l$ in $Y$. A retract is a continuous map, so will induce such a homomorphism, but in general may not be an isomorphism.

A deformation retract from $X$ to $Y$ is stronger though, and in particular implies that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, so their fundamental groups will be isomorphic. This isomorphism will be given by $r_\sharp$, where $r: X \to Y$ is the retract given by the deformation retract.